# join performance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql

I have some problems with understanding why this code return millions of rows when in group table 400000 rows. RID loop up and Index seek on t2  should return 1 row, they return all rows from group table.

```
Create table #group (IDperson uniqueidentifier, MGroup_Idx int, 
NGroup_Idx int)
create index i1 on #group (NGroup_Idx); 

-- insert some data 

SELECT * FROM #group t 
LEFT JOIN #group t2  ON t.NGroup_Idx = t2.NGroup_Idx 
AND t2.MGroup_Idx IS not NULL
WHERE ISNULL(t.MGroup_Idx, t2.MGroup_Idx) IS NOT NULL
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The problem is he cross join that you do, as Scott identified. Plus, the join condition seems over-complicated. I think this is equivalent (assuming that you do want the cross join reslts): `INNER JOIN #group t2  ON t.NGroup_Idx = t2.NGroup_Idx 
AND t2.MGroup_Idx IS not NULL`  (without a `WHERE`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what I *believe* is happening.

You're joining `group` to itself. Therefore, you're guaranteed to match all rows between `t` and `t2` at least once (as I don't see anything in your where clause to limit that). Can there be multiple rows on group that have the exact same `NGroup_Idx`? If so, each `t` row would match multiple `t2` rows.

If this is not the case, please update your question with some sample data that reproduces the unwanted behavior.